# Want to map one-to-one relation Entity framework but Shared primary key names

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have two tables with one -to-one mapping . But the Shared Primary key names should be different.

Here are the tables

```
public class User
{

    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid LicenseGuid { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public int Sequence { get; set; }
    public UserLogin UserLogin { get; set; }
}
```

And the Shared primary key other table would be

```
public class UserLogin
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

Now how to create Shared primary key with Id -> UserId in Entityframework 6
I have tried doing this

```
builder.Entity<UserLogin>()
            .HasRequired(x => x.User).WithRequiredDependent();
```

But it creates not only `UserId` as shared key but also creates `User_id` on `UserLogins` Table which is undesirable. How can I have only one UserId as shared Primary key with Table `User` with primary shared key with `Id` and `UserId` shared key on table `UserLogin` Table.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code can solve your problem

```
 public class User{
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid LicenseGuid { get; set; }
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        public int Sequence { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("Id")]
        public UserLogin UserLogin { get; set; }
    }  




public class UserLogin
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId ")]
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

but I think you can do like this

```
public class User{
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public Guid LicenseGuid { get; set; }
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        public int Sequence { get; set; }

    } 
public class UserLogin:User{
// other property
}
```

Comment: I thought that before also . But that would be actually redundant data . I dont want all user information to come into login table as the login table only contains login information though